# Connecting sentences into a question?

Tags: sentence-structure, question, subordinate-clause

I'm afraid sometimes to compose complex questions because they could mean something that I didn't mean.

My problem now is that I would translate this question

> Can you describe me the team I will work with?

into

> Können Sie mir das Team beschreiben, ich werde mit arbeiten?

It sounds a bit weird to my beginner German ears and I don't know if in this case the verb is shifted to the end of the sentence since I don't have any subordinate conjunction. If so, will it translate into

> Können Sie mir das Team beschreiben, ich mit arbeiten werde?

Or does it just go in one sentence like this:

> Können Sie mir das Team ich werde mit arbeiten beschreiben?

Google translate suggested something that I cannot trust:

> Können Sie mir den Teams werde ich mit der Arbeit beschreiben?

Comment: Google translate is awful. By far the least correct version. You should stop using it for English to German. It'll confuse you.

Comment: Oftopic : Exist out there in the wild something better that a plain dictionary ?

Comment: for what purpose?

Comment: For personal study and improvement purposes.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want the book/resource to provide exactly that goes beyond what a dictionary is offering?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is utopoic (and oftopic).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of, it doesn't matter whether it is a question or not. What you're trying to do is fit in a relative sentence. The thing about English is that it

- tends to skip relative pronouns
- moves the preposition to the end (prefix verbs anyone?)

German does neither of the two things! The structure German can do is this:

> Can you describe to me the team **with which** I will work.

Now, the only tricky part is to choose the correct relative pronoun. That depends on gender, case and number. In this example it would be "dem"

> Können Sie/Kannst du mir das Team beschreiben, mit dem ich arbeiten werde.

As for the Nebensatzkonnektor... think of relative pronouns as these things, too.

Comment: @Gerhard I fixed the "mir/mich"-issue as it wasn't part of this question.

Comment: Google translate does much better starting with your English version.

Comment: Is it wrong to use "das" instead of "mit dem"?

"Koennen Sie mir das Team beschreiben, das ich arbeiten werde"

Comment: @Solo... yes, it's very very wrong. What makes you think it could be right? Also, where did the "mit" go?

Comment: @Emanuel 
Sorry if it sounds stupid as I'm new to the language. 
At first I'm thinking in English - "Can you describe to me the team that I will work", so I have omitted the "mit". Now if I have to use "mit" then "mit dem" makes sense ( mit + Dativ ).

Comment: @Solo... well, for all your language learning journey... just because something is a certain way in English does not mean it'll be the same just with different words in another language :). The whole "that" thing is a super common mistake. People say "das" as a relative pronoun all the time because that's what they'd say in English. It's really hard to get used to not doing it but I have a suggestion for you that you can do even without knowing any gender or case... ALWAYS USE "DIE"! It has a higher chance of being right, doesn't objectify persons and trains you that it's not "das"

Comment: @Solo... and it sounds like a French accent, which many find cute.

Comment: @Solo... as for the English... I am pretty sure "working a team" and "working with a team" don't have the same meaning. The phrasing "working a team/project" doesn't work in German